# Set a 'fallback' filetype in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, it seems like if a filetype isn't recognized, it falls back to `text` / `utf-8 [unix`. Here is an example from a text file I have:

[image]

I'm not sure if 'text' is the filetype that vim detects or if 'text' just means 'no filetype detected'. Either way, I would like to have files that are opened with an undetectable filetype (including txt) files as `set ft=markdown`. How could this be done? Additionally, is it possible to save the filetype that has been manually entered for a file? For example, let's say for a particular `txt` file I change it to `set ft=rst`, can I save that somehow, such as in the `'viminfo'` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if 'text' is the filetype that vim detects or if 'text' just means 'no filetype detected'.

"Text" is a filetype. It only doesn't do much by default, but anyway... "Not detected" is an empty value of filetype.

> I would like to have files that are opened with an undetectable filetype (including txt) files as set ft=markdown. How could this be done?

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to have so many "markdowns", but, in principle, you can try to write some `:h ftdetect` script which does something like `setf FALLBACK markdown`.

Considering `*.txt` you can either reassign filetype with `ftdetect` too (need to be careful not to break "help" and such), or maybe replace it on `ftplugin` level by creating `~/.vim/ftplugin/text.vim` which forcefully does `runtime! ftplugin/markdown.vim`. The choice is yours.

> Additionally, is it possible to save the filetype that has been manually entered for a file? For example, let's say for a particular txt file I change it to set ft=rst, can I save that somehow, such as in the 'viminfo' file?

As "filetype" is an option, it can be saved into "session" file (depending on `'ssop'` value), not to "viminfo". But I'd rather suggest to put it directly into a file instead (`:h modeline`).